# How to successfully process a POST request in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and web development in general. I have a Course model in models.py. I essentially want to add courses on the frontend. I would use a POST to the server. I am just a little confused on if I am doing things correctly, or if I am missing something.

I have created an AddCourseForm class in order to try and handle this.

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    desc = CharField(max_length=150)
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    storyboard_file_path = TextField()
    storyboard_completed = BooleanField(default=False)
    filming_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    audio_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    production_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    aggregation_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    video_file_path = TextField()
    final_review_complete = BooleanField(default=False)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects", null=True, blank=True)
```

serializer.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'desc', 'name', 'storyboard_file_path', 
        'storyboard_completed', 'filming_complete', 'audio_complete',  
        'production_complete', 'aggregation_complete', 'video_file_path',
        'final_review_complete', 'course')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class CouserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'projects')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

forms.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = [
            'name'
        ]
```

views.py

```
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CouserSerializer


def add_course(request):

    if request.POST:
        course_form = AddCourseForm(request.POST)

        if course_form.is_valid():
            new_course_form = course_form.save()
            return redirect(new_course_form) #get_absolute_url set on model

        else:
            return render(request,
                'service/add_course.html',
                    {'course_form': course_form}
                    )

    else:
        course_form = AddCourseForm(
                        initial={'name': ' '}
                        )
        return render(request,
                'service/add_course.html',
                {'course_form': course_form}
                )
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'courses', views.CourseViewSet)
router.register(r'focal', views.FocalUserViewSet)
#router.register(r'add_course', views.CourseCreateViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api/', include(router.urls)),
    path(r'', views.index, name='index')
]
```

I feel like I have everything correct, but I am not sure how I would test a POST request. One question I have, is would I need to update my urls.py in any way? I am not sure how to test a POST request easily.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Your `views.py` is not complete

Comment: @HuLuViCa what is it missing?

Comment: you don't have to configure a url just to receive post, you can post to self.